¿Cual seria la mejor forma de recorrer los 256 valores de un unsigned char?
Se me ocurren dos formas, pero no se ve bonito.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char n=0;
    bool fin = false;
    while(!fin)
    {
        if(n==255)
            fin = true;
        std::cout << "n: " << static_cast<int>(n) << "\n";
        n++;
    }
    for(unsigned char a=0; ; a++)
    {
        std::cout << "a: " << static_cast<int>(a) << "\n";
        if(a==255)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "Fin\n";
}

lo otro seria usar un unsigned short int solo para recorrer el for de forma correcta pero estaria desperdiciando la mitad de la memoria.

Mejor en qué sentido? Parece una pregunta basada en opiniones

Programando para una computadora de hoy en día no hay ningún problema en desperdiciar 1 o 3 bytes. Es insignificante.

Supongo que eso penso el inventor de las "aplicaciónes web híbridas" y ahora necesitamos celulares con varios GB de RAM para algo simple, recuerda que este es un ejemplo simplificado al maximo.

Entiendo tu punto. Pero ya estamos hablando de GB. Desperdiciar 1 o 3 GB sí se siente. Le regla es  optimizar cuando es necesario, no antes.

El código no tiene porque ser "bonito", debe ser primero optimo, y después legible.

Una opción es usar el operador de post-incremento, aprovechando que devuelve el valor previo al incremento y usando dicho valor para la condición de salida en un do-while:
unsigned char n = 0;
do {
    std::cout << "n: " << static_cast<int>(n) << "\n";
}
while(n++ < 255);

Eso si, ten en cuenta que el valor de la variable de control no será 255 al terminar el ciclo, será 0. En cualquier caso, con los enteros sin signo el comportamiento si se supera el rango está perfectamente definido por el estándar, otra cosa es que consideremos su uso legible.

Edición
En mi respuesta original incluí erróneamente la opción:
for (unsigned char n = 0; n++ < 255;) {
    std::cout << "n: " << static_cast<int>(n) << "\n";
}

pero, como comenta correctamente Revista Online Occam's Razor, esto se salta el 0 y obviamente no es una opción válida si se quieren realizar las 256 iteraciones.

#FJSevilla creo que tu primer ejemplo no imprime el valor 0

RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor tienes toda la razón, error estúpido de mi parte, gracias por comentarlo. @user370267 he editado la respuesta, la opción del do-while es correcta y mi explicación orginal también, pero descarta mi opción del for..., esto me pasa por intentar ser productivo un viernes por la tarde...

Si el valor REALMENTE es un unsigned char... después del 255 no volvería a ser 0, obteniendo un bucle infinito? XD

@ArnauCastellví  efectivamente  vuelve a ser 0 pero no hay ciclo infinito porque el  do-while  se rompe al terminar  la iteracion en la que n es  255  en el  "do". El código del ejemplo no llega a usar nunca n después del "overflow", el ciclo se rompe justo en el momento en el que n pasa de 255 a 0.

La clave está en que 255++ retorna 255 no 0,  este operador "retorna" el valor actual y luego incrementa la variable (a diferencia de ++n que primero incrementa y "retorna" el valor incrementado). Cuando n vale 255 y se evalúa n++ < 255 la condición deja de cumplirse (255 < 255) y el ciclo se rompe. Como el incremento se produce aunque el ciclo se rompa justo en ese punto, al terminar el ciclo  n valdrá 0, pero el último valor que el while comprobó fue 255 jamás llega a comprobar el valor para n = 0 despúes del "overflow". No se si habre aclarado algo, si no comenta.

Otra posibilidad sería esta:
for (unsigned char n = 0; std::cout << "n: " << static_cast<int>(n++) << "\n", n;);

En este caso abusamos de que for no es más que una forma compacta de un bucle while y el operador , que nos devuelve el valor de la última expresión que incluimos.
Otra alternativa que produce el mismo código cuando activamos las optimizaciones de g++ es:
  unsigned char i = 0;
 loop:
  std::cout << "n: " << static_cast<int>(i++) << "\n";
  if (i != 0) goto loop;

Mucho más legible.
En cualquier caso, si bien el overflow de enteros no es Comportamiento Indefinido en C como te dicen más arriba, cuando se usa de forma intencional produce código más difícil de entender (salvo en contadas excepciones). Pero el código binario final, una vez activadas las optimizaciones del compilar no va diferir mucho de una versión más legible

Respuesta corta.
No hay una "mejor forma" general de hacer nada, la "mejor forma" de hacer cualquier cosa nunca será genérica si no hecha a medida para una situación concreta. Para saber si una solución es mejor que otra para una situación determinada, debe medirse el rendimiento (benchmarking) de la solución en el contexto que lo requiere.
Pero ten en cuenta que esta búsqueda del máximo rendimiento más veces que menos es innecesaria, pues la mayoría del código ni siquiera es crítico (sigue la distribución de Pareto1) y en consecuencia optimizarlo no aporta ninguna mejora perceptible; preocuparse por el rendimiento de un código sin saber si es crítico es una mala práctica que se conoce como optimización prematura.
Los efectos adversos de la optimización prematura son más notables cuando para optimizar un proceso, complicamos el código de manera que el compilador lo tiene más difícil o imposible para aplicar sus propias optimizaciones, lo cuál deriva en un código aún menos eficiente del que habría resultado sin nuestra intervención.
Respuesta larga.
Escoger un tipo de dato cuyo tamaño sea menor a la palabra de procesador va a tener un impacto nulo en el rendimiento (o en algunos casos muy concretos puede empeorarlo).
A grandes rasgos la palabra de procesador es el tamaño mínimo con el que el procesador trabaja; por ejemplo: trabajando con un procesador de 64bits, tus unsigned char al final van a ser procesados como 64bits en lugar de como 8bits, así que tus esfuerzos por optimizar la huella de memoria no tienen ningún impacto en el rendimiento general del programa.
Dicho esto, veamos el ensamblador que genera tu código (he cambiado el std::cout por print para simplificar):
# for
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], 0
.L5:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
        mov     edi, eax
        call    print(int)
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], -1
        je      .L7
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], al
        jmp     .L5

# while
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-2], 0
        jmp     .L9
.L11:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], -1
        jne     .L10
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-2], 1
.L10:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
        mov     edi, eax
        call    print(int)
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], al
.L9:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-2]
        xor     eax, 1
        test    al, al
        jne     .L11
        nop
        nop
        leave
        ret

Se puede ver claramente que la versión while genera mucho más código; es lógico pues declara y gestiona una variable adicional (fin), pero si pedimos al compilador que aplique la optimización máxima (parámetro -O) vemos que ambas funciones son casi idénticas:
# for
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 0
.L7:
        movzx   edi, bl
        call    print(int)
        cmp     bl, -1
        je      .L5
        add     ebx, 1
        jmp     .L7

# while
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 0
.L10:
        movzx   edi, bl
        call    print(int)
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     ebx, 256
        jne     .L10
        pop     rbx
        ret

Pese a que el compilador ha hecho un trabajo excelente, no debemos olvidar que el código debe ser legible y comprensible para los humanos, es mucho mejor este código:
for (int i = 0; i != 256; ++i)
    print(i);

Que es más fácil de leer y más fácil de entender y también genera un código ensamblador compacto:
# for
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 0
.L6:
        mov     edi, ebx
        call    print(int)
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     ebx, 256
        jne     .L6
        pop     rbx
        ret

Así que en resumen:

No hay una mejor forma general de hacer las cosas.
No te preocupes por el rendimiento de partes del código que no sabes si son críticas.
Si quieres optimizar una parte crítica del código, ten en cuenta que el compilador puede verse afectado de manera negativa.
No permitas que las optimizaciones hagan que tu código sea menos legible.


1El 80% del código se ejecuta un 20% del tiempo, esto tiene un impacto en el desarrollo de software.

PaperBirdMaster creo que tu último bucle es un bucle infinito. Se ve claramente en el ensamblador generado. Como bien dices al principio es mejor usar el tamaño de palabra nativo... Un ' int' . Curiosamente ese código lo usamos en un artículo en nuestro último número . Lo enlazo por si alguien tiene curiosidad por saber porque es un bucle infinito.

@RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor tienes razón, es un bucle infinito. Se me olvidó cambiar el tipo de dato en el bucle.

Aprovecho para también "hacer publicidad" de un artículo de mi autoría: La leyenda del preincremento y postincremento.

De hecho, while optimizado está tomando una instrucción menos que el for. push, pop y ret solo son parte de la gestión del stack. Una aproximación sería sumar los ciclos de reloj que el manual dice que usa. Aún así es mejor hacer un benchmark
